# Problem in javascript while submiting the form

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi I am getting null value as i am submiting the form using javascript and passing the parameter using querystring ,I am using  `request.getParameter("name")`, to get the result  ,and also i am not getting any parameter in queryString(address bar).

Please help me ....Thnx...Please ...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkempno()
{

    var empno=document.getElementById("empno");
    var empvalue=empno.value;
    alert(empvalue);
    if(empvalue=="")
    {
        alert("Employee Number is requried");
        empno.focus();
        return false;

    }

}
function checkempname()
{

    var empname=document.getElementById("empname");
    var empvalue=empname.value;
    if(empvalue==""||empvalue==null)
    {
        alert("Employee Empname is requried");
        empname.focus();
        return false;

    }

}

function calljsp(){
    var fform=document.forms["myform"];

    fform.action="result.jsp?name=jill&sex=f";
    alert(fform.action);    
    document.forms["myform"].method="GET";

    fform.submit();




}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form  id="myform">
<div id="body">
<table style="border: 1px solid black;width:60%;padding:15px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">

<tr>
<td style="text-align: center"> <input type="submit" value="Save it" style="text-align: center" ></input>   </td>
<td > <input type="reset"   value="Referesh" > </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Click this to submit the form using JScript</td>
  <td><input type="button" name="subjsript" size="30" onclick="calljsp();" value="Submit Via JScript"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Comment: It looks like you're missing the closing tag for that `<div>` called "body".

Comment: Where is it you are actually doing the submitting? This shows only your validation..

Comment: @Michael Jasper that "calljsp()" function submits the form, looks like. It's called by the "click" handler on the "Submit Via JScript" button.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code requires the form to have **name** not id, so have such form tag:

```
<form  id="myform" name="myform">
```

To save yourself such trouble though, you can pass reference to the button when calling the function:

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="calljsp(this);" ...
```

Then have such function:

```
function calljsp(oButton) {
   var fform = oButton.form;
   fform.action = "result.jsp?name=jill&sex=f";
   ...
```

This way the name doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

In your function calljsp()

use

```
  var fform = document.getElementById('myform');
```

instead of

```
 var fform=document.forms["myform"];
```